# Netstat doesn't work on FreeBSD by php function exec()

Tags: php, shell, freebsd, netstat

In my php-app I need list of all ip connected on 80 port.
i've chose this way:

```
<?php
     $ips = exec("netstat -an |grep 'tcp\|udp' | awk '{print $5}' | cut -d: -f1 | sort | uniq -c", $info);
?>
```

But it dosen't work on my VPS FreeBSD server. When I start `netstat -an` notice appears and no connections in output:

```
netstat: kvm not available: /dev/mem: No such file or directory
```

I tried to add `device mem` to conf, but i have empty /usr/src/sys. I got to the point that I need rebuild core.))

`netstat` works correctly when user is root(from console).

I haven't problem like this on CentOS hosting platform.

Can anybody help me? Or maybe another way exists for resolving this task

Comment: This question belongs on http://serverfault.com/

Comment: I asked my question over there. When i get an answer i'll close it here

Comment: Check the permissions on `/usr/bin/netstat`. It should belong to the user `root` and the group `kmem`, and it should have the setgid bit set. The device `/dev/kmem` should be readable by the `kmem` group.

Comment: `-r-xr-sr-x  1 root  kmem  157616 Apr 28 18:51 /usr/bin/netstat`    For `/dev/kmem` and `/dev/mem` No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

Do you have **safe_mode** enabled in php.ini?

> Note: When safe mode is enabled, you can only execute files within the safe_mode_exec_dir. For practical reasons, it is currently not allowed to have .. components in the path to the executable.

I recommend you start digging through http://php.net/ for more information on this. This most probably has to do with *sandboxing*, *chroot*, *jails* or other similar concepts. Note that in jails not all nodes in */dev/* are available.

Answer (score 0):

On FreeBSD uses the functions from the `kvm` libraray to read data from the running kernel. This requires access to the `/dev/mem` device.

Since you can run `netstat` normally as root, but not from PHP, I suspect that PHP is run in a [jail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeBSD_jail). The `/dev/mem` device is usually not visible in a jail.

If PHP is indeed running in a jail, and you really want to expose `/dev/mem` in that jail, you should edit `/etc/devfs.rules` and create a new ruleset that adds `/dev/mem`, like this:

```
[devfsrules_xtrajail=6]
add include $devfsrules_hide_all
add include $devfsrules_unhide_basic
add include $devfsrules_unhide_login
add path 'mem' unhide
```

Make sure that you don't use a ruleset number <5 or one that is already defined.

When starting the jail, you should set the `devfs_ruleset` parameter to the number of the ruleset you created, in this case 6.